# Capture all informations passed to a view in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to capture every information passed to view using the `afterFilter`. So I need to know:

- all variables
- session flash
- the action executed (last action)
- the view called

This is because I need to check **if the request is json** or not for change the response.

Currently I use `afterFilter` like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
  // Here's something that happens after the request
  $this->afterFilter(function() {
  });
}
```

What I want is: use the `afterFilter` method in BaseController to capture all events/actions and then decide if the request is json or not.

If you need more information, comment please.

*And sorry for my english*

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to know if JSON or if AJAX? If AJAX then just use:

```
if (Request::ajax())
{
    //
}
```

Comment: Yes, but you not understand. I know how to check if the request is json/ajax or not. What I want is: use the afterFilter method in BaseController to capture all events/actions and then decide if the request is json or not.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Request::wantsJson()` to determine if the request is asking for `json` in return using:

```
// In app/filters.php
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    if($request->wantsJson()) {
        //...
    }
});
```

In this case, `Laravel (through Base/Symfony class)` checks if the `Accept` header is set and if that is `application/json`.

Comment: Right, but how can I get all the variables returned in `return View::make('...')->with('var1', $var1)...`?

Comment: @PatrickMaciel, `$response->getOriginalContent()->getData()` will return an array of data passed to the view.

Comment: @PatrickMaciel, Also you may use `$response->getOriginalContent()->offsetGet('variableName')`.

Comment: I get this error: `Method [getOriginalContent] does not exist on Redirect.`, but is not a redirect, is just the `public function index()` [GET]